# Python socket based server side polling

Tags: python, sockets, tcp

How to continuously poll python server (TCP Socket based) for changes and server has to revert back to connected clients without request from clients??

Comment: Do you mean "How can I implement a push (aka publish/subscribe) service?"? See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology

Comment: The answer totally depends on the server and the protocol used. It might not be possible at all.

Comment: There are http-based techniques like long-polling (e.g. comet) and other non-http TCP-based protocols like MQTT (there are others) which offer much lighter-weight-than-http native publish/subscribe capability. Plenty of information can be found by goggling for, maybe, _python server push_